# Android cuts accelerometer measurements on wearables

Tags: android, acceleration, wearables

I found that on android there is a 2G limit of acceleration on the most watches that I tried. I am wondering is there a way to get a better range of measurements, and is that for every watch with android or it is different? What is the max acceleration that you noticed on your watch?

Comment: Technically, it's a better _range_ of measurement that you're after (better _resolution_ would be going 1G to 1.2G to 1.23G -- being able to distinguish smaller and smaller differences in acceleration). </pedant>

Comment: Thanks for info ;)